# TSQL- Split the dates into months

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

[image]

I would like the following result set to be split into months :

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xya2C.png]

Comment: please provide data and expected results as text in your question, [not as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: What is your question here? What was your attempt? Why isn't it working? [so] isn't a free coding service, so don't treat it like one. it's a Q&A website for programming based questions.

Answer (score 2):

You need to expand out each source row by `DATEDIFF(MONTH, StartFrom, StartTo) + 1` times.

One way of doing this would be to join onto a table with sequential integers. Another way  ([demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019l&fiddle=acf309b456af40d1dd55bbaf9b995b62)) would be to `CROSS APPLY` on an expression that returns the desired number of rows. Below I use `OPENJSON` for this purpose (as this returns a handy `index` column that can be used to get the desired month).

```
SELECT T.IdNumber,
       StartFrom = IIF(DATEDIFF(MONTH, c.MonthStart, T.StartFrom) = 0, T.StartFrom, c.MonthStart),
       StartTo = IIF(DATEDIFF(MONTH, c.MonthStart, T.StartTo) = 0, T.StartTo, EOMONTH(c.MonthStart))
FROM   #T T
       CROSS APPLY (SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1, EOMONTH(DATEADD(MONTH, j.[key] + 0, StartFrom), -1))
                    FROM   OPENJSON(CONCAT('[0', REPLICATE(',0', DATEDIFF(MONTH, StartFrom, StartTo)), ']')) AS j
                    ) c(MonthStart)
```

Comment: Thank you ,this worked , i am able to get the desired data

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have a calendar table, you can use an ad-hoc tally table in concert with a simple JOIN.

You can set a more appropriate start date other than `2000-01-01`

**Example**

```
Select IDNumber
      ,StartFrom = min(D)
      ,StartTo   = max(D)
 From  YourTable A
 Join  (
        Select Top 10000 D=DateAdd(DAY,-1+Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select Null)),convert(date,'2000-01-01')) 
         From  master..spt_values n1,master..spt_values n2
       ) B on D between StartFrom and StartTo
 Group By idnumber,year(D),month(D)
```

Comment: Thank you ,this version also worked.